# How to get partition path from hive-metastore given a Timestamp object as the partition key

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, hive, hive-metastore

In spark, is there a way to get the partition path by providing a Timstamp object, instead of providing the partition key as a string?

I know that we can get the partition path by running the following query:

```
val x = "date='2019-08-06 23:48:32.113'"
spark.sql(s"describe extended hospitaltest partition (${x})")
```

but the above query requires the partition key as a string.

Comment: Can you give an example how you are planning to create a timestamp object? As far as i think, it has to be passed an a string.

Comment: @Goldie I am creating the timestamp object from a java date object by using java date's getTime method. So if another app wants to know the mapping between a Timestamp object and the actual partition path, how can it get the answer without knowing what date format is being used? Or on the other hand, if given a partition path as a string, how can it know which date this string represents without knowing the format?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the query it's written correctly for spark, but as part of your question, the next query returns the location of a partition, from hive metastore (stored in mysql):

```
SELECT 
      location 
    FROM 
      hive.DBS 
    LEFT JOIN hive.TBLS 
    ON 
      ( 
        DBS.DB_ID       = TBLS.DB_ID 
      AND upper(TBLS.tbl_name) = 'CG_CRDSTDLVRS_RAW' 
      ) 
    LEFT JOIN hive.PARTITIONS 
    ON 
      ( 
        TBLS.TBL_ID = PARTITIONS.TBL_ID 
      AND PARTITIONS.PART_NAME LIKE '%2018-09-15%' 
      ) 
    LEFT JOIN hive.SDS 
    ON 
      ( 
        PARTITIONS.SD_ID = SDS.SD_ID 
      ) 
    WHERE 
      upper(DBS.name)='RAW_FAT01'
```